# Trouble With GROUP BY and JOIN on SQL

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have 2 tables one with Employee names and Employee Codes, the other with the same employee codes but with the employee's arrival and departure time. One column on the latter table contains a varchar that states whether they arrived late or early and the table shows values for 3 days and 6 employees.
I need to use join to show the first and last name from the first table with every column from the second table and also not show employees that have arrived late one or more times.
The broken code I have now is:

```
SELECT 
    EmpRegister.LastName, 
    EmpRegister.FirstName, 
    TimeSheet.* 
FROM EmpRegister 
    INNER JOIN TimeSheet ON EmpRegister.ID=TimeSheet.EmpID 
WHERE Flag <> 'Late'
GROUP BY Emp.ID
```

Comment: Can  you provide the sample data that you have and your expected output?

Comment: You cannot GROUP BY if you want to show all timesheet entries for the give employee.

Comment: Using `WHERE Flag <> 'Late'` doesn't work because it is applied to each row, not all rows for the client. Perhaps you were trying to overcome that with the `GROUP BY` but that isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Try `WHERE NOT EXISTS (  )` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time to make up a set of test data, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    EmpRegister.LastName, 
    EmpRegister.FirstName, 
    TimeSheet.* 
FROM EmpRegister 
INNER JOIN TimeSheet 
    ON EmpRegister.ID=TimeSheet.EmpID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM TimeSheet 
  WHERE  EmpRegister.ID = TimeSheet.EmpID
  AND Flag = 'Late'
  )
```